# VBA type mismatch at rows.cut

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problem with cutting multiple worksheets and putting it into one. I'm getting "Type mismatch" error. Can you look at my code?

```
Public Sub Conc()
Dim ws  As Worksheet
Dim LR1 As Integer
Dim LR2 As Integer
Dim LR3 As Integer
Dim first As Integer
LR1 = 0
LR2 = 0
LR3 = 0
first = 1
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Conc"
End With

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Conc" Then
        LR1 = Sheets("Conc").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        LR2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LR3 = LR1 + LR2
        Worksheets(ws).Rows(first & ":" & LR2).Cut
        Worksheets("Conc").Rows(LR1 & ":" & LR3).Insert
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Build your string like this `first & ":" & LR2`.  Same idea for the Insert.

Comment: Error still occurs

Comment: Worksheets(ws) should be just ws perhaps?

Comment: That was it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Public Sub Conc()

    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Log, LR3 As Long
    Dim first As Integer

    LR1 = 0
    LR2 = 0
    LR3 = 0
    first = 1

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Conc"
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conc")
        LR1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Conc" Then

            With ws

                LR2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                LR3 = LR1 + LR2
                .Rows(first & ":" & LR2).Cut
            End With

            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Conc").Rows(LR1 & ":" & LR3).Insert

        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Still nothing. But I think the LR1 and LR2 are fine. When using MsgBox to show their value it works perfectly.

Comment: @Stloax see edited answer. I try to tidy up  the code in order to be more understandable.

Comment: It was problem with Worksheets(ws) so your solution was good.

Comment: nice to hear that i help